# C void function modify pointer array

Tags: c

I have a function tokenize and I want to modify a char pointer array through the function. But I don't get the result after many tries. Could someone help me?

Below is the code:

```
void **tokenize(char **argv, char *line, int *numTokens, char *delimiter)
{
    int argc = 0;
    char *token = strtok(line, delimiter);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        argv[argc++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }
    argv[argc++] = NULL;
    *numTokens = argc - 1;
}

void process_cmd(char *cmdline){
    char *temp[20];
    int *num2;

    tokenize(temp, cmdline, num2, "|"); 

    printf("%s\n", temp[0]);
    printf("%s\n", temp[1]);
    printf("%d\n", *num2);

}
```

Comment: Where is `num2` pointing? Perhaps you should take more time to study how emulating pass by reference in C really works, and how to use the address-of operator `&`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your `process_cmd` function, the local variable `num2` is not initialized when it is defined, and you use it directly at the call to `tokenize`. And you write to the location pointed to by `numTokens` in `tokenize`, which results in an undefined behavior. In most cases your program will crash when trying to write through `numTokens`; but theoretically anything could happen.

To fix this, you need to change your definition of `num2` to:

```c
int num2;
```

and call `tokenize` as follows:

```c
tokenize(temp, cmdline, &num2, "|");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.